SQL Data Group and Formating
I have a table like the one on the left. I want to transform this table into the one on the right. Is it possible with SQL? If so, how can I do it?

First cvn = Lowest score for
Last cvn  = Highest Score



I couldn't find any way.

SELECT 
    st.trq_id,      
    sdpl."/TMCSL/CVN_NUM",
    sp1."STOP_ID"
        

FROM SAPHANADB."/SCMTMS/D_TRQROT" AS st
INNER JOIN SAPHANADB."/SCMTMS/D_TORITE" AS s2 ON
    s2.trq_id = st.trq_id
    AND s2.item_type = 'CONT'
    AND s2.item_cat = 'TUR'
    AND s2.provision_req <> 'P'
    AND s2.empty_return_req <> 'R'
INNER JOIN SAPHANADB."/SCMTMS/D_TORROT" AS sd2 ON
    sd2.db_key = s2.parent_key
    AND sd2.tor_cat = 'TU'
INNER JOIN SAPHANADB."/SCMTMS/D_TORSTP" AS sp1 ON
    sd2.db_key = sp1.parent_key
    AND sp1.stop_cat = 'O'
    AND sp1.log_locid <> ''
    AND (
        sp1."/TMCSL/LOC_ROLE" = '3'
        OR sp1."/TMCSL/LOC_ROLE" = '5'
        OR sp1."/TMCSL/LOC_ROLE" = '7'
    )
INNER JOIN SAPHANADB."/SCMTMS/D_SCHDPL" AS sdpl ON
    sdpl.db_key = sp1."/TMCSL/ASGN_SCHED_STOP_KEY"
    AND sdpl."/TMCSL/CVN_NUM" <> ''
    AND sdpl.del_flag = ''
INNER JOIN SAPHANADB."/SCMTMS/D_SCHDEP" AS sdep ON
    sdep.db_key = sdpl.parent_key
    AND sdep.del_flag = ''
    AND sdep."/TMCSL/VOYAGE_TYPE" = 'EX'


What issue do you have with MIN, MAX and GROUP BY?

I am new with SQL and ı couldnt figure out :(

I'd skip the GROUP BY, and go with window functions instead.

This can be achieved by using the FIRST_VALUE and LAST_VALUE aggregation functions with an ORDER BY clause.
select
    id,
    first_value(cvn order by score) as first_cvn,
    last_value(cvn order by score) as last_cvn
from source
group by id


Something like this, using Window Functions as @jarlh suggested:
create table #source
(
    id int,
    score int,
    cvn varchar(2)
)

insert into #source values
(123,1,'ab'),
(123,2,'ac'),
(123,3,'ad'),
(4321,1,'x'),
(4321,2,'v')

select distinct
    id,
    first_value(cvn) over (partition by id order by score) as first_cvn,
    first_value(cvn) over (partition by id order by score desc) as last_cvn
from #source
order by id

drop table #source

Returns the expected results:
+------+-----------+----------+
| id   | first_cvn | last_cvn |
+======+===========+==========+
| 123  | ab        | ad       |
+------+-----------+----------+
| 4321 | x         | v        |
+------+-----------+----------+

